# unexpected C output

Tags: c, constants, printf, escaping, string-literals

This program ...

```
int main(void)
{
printf("CASSIUS"+'\11');
return 0;
}
```

... compiles successfully, but with:

> ```
> **Warning** main.c:13:8: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
>  printf("CASSIUS"+'\11');
> ```

Would you please explain why the output is 0?

Comment: For me it outputs "8". What are you trying to do with the printf? It's not the normal format.

Comment: What did you expect the output to be?

Comment: It would make a little more sense -- but only a little -- if you changed it to, for example, `printf("CASSIUS"+'\03');`.  But I second Owl's question: what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this call

```
printf("CASSIUS"+'\11');
```

there is used the pointer arithmetic. The string literal "CASSIUS" is converted to pointer to its first element to which the integer character constant that is equal to 9 in decimal is added. And the result pointer points beyond the string literal.  So the program has undefined behavior.

Bear in mind that the value of the octal integer character constant '\11' is equivalent to the escape sequence '\t'.

Thus the expression in whole does not make a sense.

If you wanted for example to append the output with the new line character you could write

```
printf("CASSIUS" "\12");
```

or

```
printf("CASSIUS" "\n");
```

or just

```
printf("CASSIUS\n");
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be defined like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: can you please explain to me how does the compiler know that `'\11'` is in octal?

Comment: @AdityaMishra The compiler knows because the C standard says it is in octal.

Comment: @AdityaMishra It is by the definition of  character constant. octal-escape-sequence:
\ octal-digit
\ octal-digit octal-digit
\ octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit

Answer (score 3):

The constant `'\11'` has value 9. The string literal `"CASSIUS"` is an array length 8 of `char` (including the null terminator character). The expression `"CASSIUS"+'\11'` points to the 9th element (counting from 0) of the string literal which is two elements beyond the last element (with index 7) of the array. This is a "pointer overflow" which is an example of *undefined behavior*.<sup>1</sup> Undefined behavior also occurs when the `printf` function dereferences this invalid pointer.

―
<sup>1</sup> It is allowed to construct a pointer value that points one element past the last element of the array without pointer overflow, although dereferencing such a pointer also results in undefined behavior.

---

The warning from GCC `warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]` is because GCC is unable to check that the `printf` format specifier parameter is consistent with the other `printf` parameters unless the format specifier parameter is specified as a string literal (or as a concatenation of string literals).