# clang: <string literal> + <expression returning int> leads to confusing warning: adding 'int' to a string does not append to the string

Tags: c, clang, compiler-warnings, c11

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
  bool flag = true;
  printf("%s\n", "xxxzzz" + ( flag ? 3 : 0 ));
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with `-std=c11 -pedantic` leads to warning:

```
main.c:7:27: warning: adding 'int' to a string does not append to the string
      [-Wstring-plus-int]
  printf("%s\n", "xxxzzz" + ( flag ? 3 : 0 ));
                 ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:7:27: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
  printf("%s\n", "xxxzzz" + ( flag ? 3 : 0 ));
                          ^
                 &        [                 ]
1 warning generated.
```

However, this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
  bool flag = true;
  printf("%s\n", ("xxxzzz") + ( flag ? 3 : 0 ));
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with `-std=c11 -pedantic` leads to no warning.

Why this warning?

Why does the `()` matter?

P.S. gcc / msvc generate no warnings in both cases.

Comment: This is a specific compiler internals question, and not the language. I'd speculate that the parentheses are somehow hinting the compiler that you know what you are doing. There are different ways of silencing the compiler warnings, and this is one of them for this specific compiler.

Comment: Wouldn't `"xxxzzz" [flag ? 3 : 0 ]` be less confusing?

Comment: @EdHeal `&"xxxzzz" [flag ? 3 : 0 ]` actually

Comment: I wonder if clang implemented this warning specifically to address [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68713503/unexpected-c-output)? :-)

Comment: @EdHeal Nope, it would be a pointer to a `char`

Comment: @EdHeal : Agreed esp. since the message includes `note: use array indexing to silence this warning`

Comment: One guess would be that internally, the [AST](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html) node for the expression `"xxxzzz"` carries a tag that says "this is a string literal", and the compiler generates a warning when an expression with that tag appears as one operand of `+`.  But that tag might not be propagated up the tree, so the expression `("xxxzzz")` may not "inherit" the tag from its subexpression `"xxxzzz"`, and thus no warning when you use it with `+`.

Comment: It's a warning to catch a very specific type of beginner mistake, so it's not surprising that it is targeted at the particular form in which that mistake most commonly appears, rather than trying to be more general.  You could report this as a clang bug if you like, but my guess is that it would have low priority.

Comment: You say the warning is "confusing", but hopefully you understand its intent: a beginner coming from a language like Javascript might expect that `+` can be used to concatenate strings, and that an object like an integer would be converted to a string and then concatenated.  So they might think that `"xxxzzz" + 3` would yield the string `"xxxzzz3"`.  The warning is meant for those beginners, nothing more than that.

Comment: @NateEldredge Under `-pedantic` the user expects that clang warns on language extensions. However, it seems that `<string literal> + <expression returning int>` is not an extension.

Comment: `clang` warns about this even without `-pedantic`: https://godbolt.org/z/rYdzGoGz7.  The `-pedantic` flag *adds* warnings about code that uses extensions; it doesn't suppress all other warnings.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks. About the bug report. The situation is that the end user 1) supplied `-std=c11 -pedantic`, 2) expected to see no warnings (for example, because of "compile for no warnings" policy). However, clang generates warnings. Hence, the end user is confused, because the code is strictly conforming program, for which compiler generates diagnostics.

Comment: That's not a bug, then.  The user's expectation of (2) is incorrect.  Compilers are always free to generate diagnostics for strictly conforming programs, if they happen to think such diagnostics will be helpful to the programmer.  Nothing in the standard forbids that; 5.1.1.3 says diagnostics "need not" be produced in other circumstances; it doesn't say "must not".

Comment: clang in particular has some set of warnings enabled by default, of which this is one; the user can enable more warnings with options like `-Wall`, `-pedantic`, and so on.  I'm not sure if there is an option for "issue those diagnostics which are absolutely required by the standard, and no others".  The option `-Wno-everything` suppresses all warnings but it also suppresses about extensions.

Comment: The "bug" I mentioned would be only the fact that the warning is issued for `"xxxzzz"` but not for `("xxxzzz")`, when arguably it would be more consistent, and maybe more useful, to issue it for both.  It is in no way a conformance issue - it's only that the current behavior, while entirely conformant, may not be what the developers intended, or what the user would really want.  It is, as I said, an extremely minor bug if any, and may even be intentional (so that `()` can be used to suppress the warning).

Comment: @NateEldredge _Compilers are always free to generate diagnostics for strictly conforming programs, if they happen to think such diagnostics will be helpful to the programmer_: great, thanks! Yes, the tag might be lost (not propagated) in case of `()`.

Comment: @pmor, no, your interpretation of the meaning of gcc's `-pedantic` option is incorrect (and therefore it is also incorrect for other implementations that emulate gcc options).  `-pedantic` has the effect of ensuring that all the diagnostics that the language specification requires a conforming implementation to emit are in fact emitted, and *rejects* some programs, but that does not imply that all uses of extensions will trigger diagnostics.

Comment: The GCC manual in fact has long contained a remark speaking explicitly to this point: "Some users try to use `-Wpedantic` to check programs for strict ISO C conformance. They soon find that it does not do quite what they want: it finds some non-ISO practices, but not all—only those for which ISO C *requires* a diagnostic, and some others for which diagnostics have been added" (emphasis in the original).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks. About `gcc -pedantic`: there is this quote: "A feature to report any failure to conform to ISO C might be useful in some instances, but would require considerable additional work and would be quite different from -Wpedantic. We don't have plans to support such a feature in the near future.".

Comment: You could use `-Wno-string-plus-int` to suppress that specific warning.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Would the project "C compiler, which reports any failure to conform to ISO C" be useful?

Comment: Perhaps, @pmor, with the understanding that some language requirements apply to runtime behaviors that cannot, in general, be checked at compile time.  But you should also consider that as far as I know, no such project has yet emerged (closest would probably be `lint` and similar).  That probably points to a perception among people qualified to undertake such a project that the result would not be worth the effort required, at least relative to other projects that could be undertaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning is simply because the code is non-idiomatic (i.e. unusual use of pointer arithmetic), and people coming from other languages might expect an automatic string conversion of the RHS to create `"xxxzzz3"` or `"xxxzzz0"`.

It is the compiler spotting code patterns perhaps common in other languages but which have different and possibly unexpected semantics in C.  It is trying to be helpful and prevent common bugs.

In any case its suggestion to use array indexing semantics is probably the better solution in terms of clear semantics, but using parentheses clearly has the same effect of supressing the warning.

Comment: Similar to warnings for things like `if ( x = 3 )`, which you can shut up by writing `if ( (x = 3) )` to indicate, "yes, I *know* I'm using `=` instead of `==`".